# Parsing XML From an API - Python

Tags: python, xml

I'm pulling some data from an API that is returned as XML and trying to pass it through to another function to parse it.

I plan on running a for loop to iterate through hundreds of API requests and don't want to save the XML and then read it.

I keep getting `"error:TypeError: invalid file:"` when trying to run it.

See below for sample code and data strucutre.

Code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 

data = ''

def pulldata():
    global data
    data = xmlfromapi

def parse():
    tree = ET.parse(data)
    root = tree.getroot()

pulldata()
parse()
```

XML Structure:

```
<Data reqId=1, data=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report Major="1" Minor="0" Revision="1">
<Infos>
<Info Type="RepNo">CA</Info>
<InfoType="Name">John</Info>
<Info Type="No">2019</Info>
<Info Type=No">000</Info>
</Infos>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Even when I delete the global vairable and put everything in pulldata() I get an invalid file error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an incorrect XML syntax in the file. Please use the recommended XML syntax. Correct your XML schema and you should be fine I guess. See [example](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_example.asp) here.
EDIT: Here's your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Report Major="1" Minor="0" Revision="1">
    <Infos>
        <Info Type="RepNo">CA</Info>
        <Info Type="Name">John</Info>
        <Info Type="No">2019</Info>
        <Info Type="No">000</Info>
    </Infos>
</Report>
```

Comment: You were right. There were xml errors scattered throughout the xml. 

Used str.replace() to remove the pieces of code causing the errors. 

Thanks for the help! Much appreciated.